# Is ARB_texture_multisample available for OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Basically, what is needed to perform multisampled deferred shading.

To expand a bit: I'm not actually all that interested in Deferred shading per se, but what is of key importance is allowing the storage and retrieval of sub-pixel sample data for antialiasing purposes: I need to be able to control the resolve, or at least do some operations before resolving multisampled buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the major extensions for OpenGL ES are listed here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/

And as far as I know currently no major OpenGL ES implmentations does not provide individual sample resolving using OpenGL ES. Only thing you can do is to copy multisampled texture to normal one, and the access "normal" samples.

Comment: Thanks. Can you fix your second sentence so I can be sure you mean what I think you mean?

Comment: What I wanted to say is written here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Multisampling_Considerations "It is an error to blit between buffers with different numbers of samples, unless one of them has zero samples. You get this by not attaching multisampled images to that FBO, or not using multisampled default framebuffers."

Comment: So, basically, these hardware do not give me control of the resolve step (access the samples themselves from shader).